# Using OR statment in condition sqlite database

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, sqlite

I'm try to execute this query but not working in sqlite android database

```
"select CLFPSid from CheckLists where CLFPid = "+ section + " and ActionDate ='"+Date+"'and CLFPSid = 0 or 3 or 4 or 5"
```

the problem in using OR statment , note that CLFPSid  is of type integer .

how to use or sqlite condition statement ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write

```
CLFPSid = 0 or 3 or 4 or 5
```

You should use the IN clause:

```
CLFPSid IN (0, 3, 4, 5);
```

Comment: +1, `IN` is a much better standard for this than `statement or statement or statement`

Answer (score 1):

Change your query as follows

```
 "select CLFPSid from CheckLists where CLFPid = "+ section + " 
           and ActionDate ='"+Date+"'and CLFPSid = 0 or CLFPSid = 3 
                                              or CLFPSid = 4 or CLFPSid = 5"
```

Comment: Don't you need ( after the last `and` and ) after the `= 5` ?

Comment: @peter.petrov not a must.

Comment: IN statement is much better and simple

Comment: Hm. I think it is a must because `a and b and c1 or c2 or c3` will be treated as `(a and b and c1) or c2 or c3` and not as `a and b and (c1 or c2 or c3)`. No? And the OP wants the latter, I think.